# Function equality assertion broken by code coverage report

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, karma-runner, istanbul

I'm working on a testing framework. To assert that two functions are equal i'm using:

```
var a = function(){ return 5; };
var b = function(){ return 5; };

var areEqual = (a.toString() == b.toString());
```

I'm running some test with karma and everything was fine until I added a test coverage report with the karma-coverage report. The assertion above is failing because Istanbul seems to be adding code two the functions.

```
a.toString()
```

Looks like:

```
function () {
  __cov_Mgz6NtZP5n6U6J27W7D4rA.f['33']++;
  __cov_Mgz6NtZP5n6U6J27W7D4rA.s['152']++;
  return 5;
}
```

I tried with:

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
var a = function(){ return 5; };
/* istanbul ignore next */
var b = function(){ return 5; };
```

But it doesn't seem to work. Do you know how can I work around this issue.

Comment: What is the point to check functions equality?

Comment: I'm working on a framework for testing and I wan't to allow developers to check if two objects are equal, it should work with all the possible data types including functions. It is working but I would like to be able to run a code coverage report.

Answer (score 2):

The best option so far is to separate your coverage in another karma configuration. You will be able to run both, like

`grunt karma:units`

and

`grunt karma:coverage`

And on the units the code wont be obfuscated

Answer (score 1):

You can remove istanbul injections using regular expressions.

```
var aStr = a.toString();
// function () {__cov_Mgz6NtZP5n6U6J27W7D4rA.f['33']++;__cov_Mgz6NtZP5n6U6J27W7D4rA.s['152']++;return 5;}

var aCleanStr = aStr.replace(/__cov.*?;/g, '');
// function () {return 5;}
```

Expression is `/__cov.*?;/g`, where

- `__cov` - will match a substring starting with `__cov`
- `.*?;` - will match any character until the very first `;`, because there might be some code between istanbul injections, `?` here represents 'non-greedy' option
- flag `g` - remove all those entries from the string